# Prove $\int_\limits{0}^{\infty} n^4 t^2e^{-2nt} dt$ divergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, improper-integrals

> Show that $x_n(t)=n^2 te^{-nt}$ does not converge in $L_2(\mathbb{R_+})$.

$\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}(n^2 te^{-nt})^2dt=\int_\limits{0}^{\infty} n^4 t^2e^{-2nt} dt\geqslant\int_\limits{0}^{\infty} n^2 t^2e^{-2nt} dt$.

I tried to find a smaller integral that would diverge but I cannot lower the value more I cannot increase.

**Question:**

How should I prove the convergence?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That integral clearly converges for all $n$. I think you are supposed to show that the sequence of functions $(x_n)$ does not have a limit in $L^2(\Bbb{R}_+)$. In other words, that there is no function $f\in L^2$ such that $||x_n-f||\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the substitution $nt=x$ and $n\,\mathrm dt=\mathrm dx$, you get the integral$$n\int_0^{+\infty}x^2e^{-2x}\,\mathrm dx.$$But the integral $\int_0^{+\infty}x^2e^{-2x}\,\mathrm dx$ converges to some number greater than $0$ and therefore your sequence of integrals diverges.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the integral explicitly using integration by parts:

\begin{align}
n^4\int_0^\infty t^2 e^{-2nt}\,dt &= n^4\left[-\frac{t^2}{2n}e^{-2nt}\Bigg|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty 2t \left(-\frac1{2n} e^{-2nt}\right)\,dt\right]\\
&= n^3\int_0^\infty te^{-2nt}\,dt\\
&= n^3 \left[-\frac{t}{2n}e^{-2nt}\Bigg|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty  \left(-\frac1{2n} e^{-2nt}\right)\,dt\right]\\
&= \frac{n^2}2 \int_0^\infty e^{-2nt}\,dt\\
&= \frac{n}4 e^{-2nt}\Bigg|_0^\infty\\
&= \frac{n}4\\
\end{align}

which goes to $+\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.